# Combining 2 CSV files

Tags: php

I'm trying to combine two CSV files in PHP. I'm looking for perfect method. Here's my code so far:

```
$one = fopen('data5.csv', 'r');
$two = fopen('userdata.csv', 'r');

$final = fopen('final_data.csv', 'a');

$temp1 = fread($one, filesize("data5.csv"));
$temp2 = fread($two, filesize("userdata.csv"));

fwrite($final, $temp1); 
fwrite($final, $temp2);
```

Comment: Or,if you no longer need the original data you could read line by line the second csv and append it to the first. When finished,remove second csv and rename the first..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I will give you a solution to use if you have big CVSs and you don't want to use much of your machine's RAM (imagine each CSV is 1GB, for example).

```
<?php
function joinFiles(array $files, $result) {
    if(!is_array($files)) {
        throw new Exception('`$files` must be an array');
    }

    $wH = fopen($result, "w+");

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $fh = fopen($file, "r");
        while(!feof($fh)) {
            fwrite($wH, fgets($fh));
        }
        fclose($fh);
        unset($fh);
        fwrite($wH, "\n"); //usually last line doesn't have a newline
    }
    fclose($wH);
    unset($wH);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<?php
joinFiles(array('join1.csv', 'join2.csv'), 'join3.csv');
```

**Fun fact:**

I just used this to concat 2 CSV files of ~500,000 lines each. It took around 5seconds and used 512kb of memory.

**Logic:**

Open each file, read one line and then write it to the output file. Yes, it may be slower writing each line rather than writing a whole buffer, but this allows the usage of heavy files while being gentle on the memory of the machine.
At any point, you are safe because the script only reads on line at a time and then writes it.

Enjoy!

Comment: How can we join multiple files while running a loop on the joinFiles array.

Something like this:

'
for ($f = 1; $f <= 98; $f++) {
joinFiles(array());
}
'

Answer (score 4):

How about...

```
file_put_contents('final_data.csv',
    file_get_contents('data5.csv') .
    file_get_contents('userdata.csv')
);
```

Note that this loads the entire files into PHP memory though. So, if they are big, you may get memory_limit issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just concatenate the two files you can do this easily with executing a shell script assuming you are on unix like os:

```
exec("cat data5.csv > final_data.csv && cat userdata.csv >> final_data.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();  
$dir1 = "csv/2014-01/";  
$dir = $_REQUEST['folder_name'];  
$totalfiles =  count(glob($dir."/*",GLOB_BRACE));  
echo "Total files in folder = ".$totalfiles;  
if ($opend = opendir($dir)){  
    $i =0;  $final_array_export= array();  
    $fil_csv =end(explode('/',$dir));  
        $file_name = 'download/'.$fil_csv.'.csv';
        $file_cre = fopen($file_name,"w");
        $headers = array("header1","header2");
        fputcsv($file_cre,$headers);
        while (($file = readdir($opend)) !== false){
            $filename = $dir.'/'.$file;
            $files = fopen($filename,"r");
            if($files){
                $fullarray = fgetcsv($files);
                $head=array();
                if(count($fullarray) >0){    
                    foreach($fullarray as $headers){    
                        $head[] = $headers;  
                    }
                }

                while($data =  fgetcsv($files,0,",")){
                    if(count($data) >0 && count($head) >0){
                        $array_combine = array_combine($head,$data);
                    }

                    fputcsv($file_cre,$array_combine);  
                }
            }
        }

        fclose($file_cre);
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header('Content-Description: File Download');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file_name));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file_name);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.