# How to Merge CSV Files in PHP, Line by Line

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I am trying to merge several CSV files together in PHP. I already have them merged as whole files using PHP thanks to the thread here ([Combining 2 CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417734/combining-2-csv-files)), however I am looking to merge the files together by individual line.

I would like to read line 1 from `CSV 1`, line 1 from `CSV 2`, and so forth, then proceed to `line 2, 3, etc.` - Cycling between the files in the array with each loop. I have not worked with parsing files in PHP much, so I'm not sure where to begin to accomplish this.

This is what I am trying to accomplish, in case the above was not clear:

> CSV1 - Line 1
>
> CSV2 - Line 1
>
> CSV3 - Line 1
>
> CSV1 - Line 2
>
> CSV2 - Line 2
>
> CSV3 - Line 2
>
> CSV1 - Line 3
>
> CSV2 - Line 3
>
> CSV3 - Line 3

.... And continue to loop until there are no lines left in the CSV files.

Comment: Right now I am using the code from the best answer in the thread above.

Comment: Pretty simple: open 3 csv files for reading, and create 1 for writing; fgets() from each of the 3 in turn and (if the fgets returned a line) use fputs to write it to the new file; then close all files when finished

Comment: @MarkBaker Only if OP actually means lines, not rows. A CSV row can include linebreaks, in which case `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @lafor - the "what I'm trying to accomplish" example suggests lines rather than rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this php code (gets the lines with `file()`).:

```
<?php
$csv1 = file('csv1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv2 = file('csv2.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv3 = file('csv3.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines = max(count($csv1), count($csv2), count($csv3));
$finalcsv = array();
for($i=0; $i<$lines; $i++) {
  if(isset($csv1[$i])) $finalcsv[] = $csv1[$i];
  if(isset($csv2[$i])) $finalcsv[] = $csv2[$i];
  if(isset($csv3[$i])) $finalcsv[] = $csv3[$i];
}

file_put_contents('final_data.csv', implode(PHP_EOL, $finalcsv));
```