# Combining csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

help collect from 2 files csv - one. To merge similar cell. An example is shown below, and part of my code.
I would be very grateful for the help and thanks in advance

csv1.csv =

```
name;price
Tom;1000
Anna;2000
Aleks;3000
Maikal;2000
Piter;5000
```

csv2.csv =

```
name;price
Tom;1200
Anna;2300
Andre;2000
Maikal2;2400
```

all.csv - The resulting file.

```
name;price;price
Aleks;3000;
Andre;;2000
Anna;2000;2300
Piter;5000;
Maikal;2000;
Maikal2;;2400
Tom;1000;1200
```

I have a script that simply glued file based on 1 line. But it gives a different result.

```
if(@$_FILES["DATAF_1"]["size"]>0 AND @$_FILES["DATAF_2"]["size"]>0)
 {
    $data=array();
        function read_csv($file)
        {
        $out=array();
        $lines = file($file);

            foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
            {
                $out[]=explode(";",$line);
            }
        return $out;
        }

        function action_csv(&$array,$input)
        {
            for ($i=0; $i<count($input); $i++)
            {
                for ($i2=1; $i2<count($input[$i]); $i2++) {
                if(trim($input[$i][0])!=""){$array[trim($input[$i][0])][]=trim($input[$i][$i2]);}
                }
            }
        }

        function form_csv($data)
        {
        $out=array();
            foreach ($data as $line_num => $line)
            {
                $out[]=$line_num.";".implode(";",$line);
            }
        return implode("\r\n",$out);
        }

    $data1=read_csv($_FILES["DATAF_1"]["tmp_name"]);
    $data2=read_csv($_FILES["DATAF_2"]["tmp_name"]);
    action_csv($data,$data1);
    action_csv($data,$data2);


    @unlink("out.csv");
    $fp = fopen ("out.csv", "w+");
    fwrite ($fp, form_csv($data));
    fclose ($fp);
```

Comment: It might be more helpful if you detailed your current output, and the output you expect from your script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sample output is shown in Example all.csv. Or you need something else?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251862/how-to-merge-csv-files-in-php-line-by-line

Comment: Does not fit the other end needed =(

Comment: I’d read the data into an array, using the first column value as key. Loop over the first CSV file, put data into array, then loop over second file, see if key already exists – if so, append price value from second file, else create new array entry for name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code without the $_Files (just from the filesystem) and it works. So the Problem might be in the file uploade and not in the code you posted.

EDIT:
So now it should work as you wish:

```
function genAllIndexes(&$array,&$maxIndex){
    foreach($array as &$line){
        for($i = 0; $i < $maxIndex; $i++){
            if(!isset($line[$i])){
                $line[$i] = "";
            }
        }
        ksort($line);
    }
}
function action_csv(&$array,$input, &$counter){
    for ($i=0; $i<count($input); $i++){
        for ($i2=1; $i2<count($input[$i]); $i2++) {
            if(trim($input[$i][0])!=""){
                $array[trim($input[$i][0])][$counter]=trim($input[$i][$i2]);
            }
        }
    }
    $counter++;
}
$data1=read_csv('data1.csv');
$data2=read_csv('data2.csv');

$counter = 0;
action_csv($data,$data1, $counter);
action_csv($data,$data2, $counter);
genAllIndexes($data, $counter);
ksort($data);


@unlink("out.csv");
$fp = fopen ("out.csv", "w+");
fwrite ($fp, form_csv($data));
fclose ($fp);
```

Comment: `name;price;price
Tom;1000;1200
Anna;2000;2300
Aleks;3000
Maikal;2000
Piter;5000
Andre;2000
Maikal2;2400`  so it turns out. And it's not quite what I need.

Comment: do you need it exactly like that: name;price;price
Aleks;3000;
Andre;;2000
Anna;2000;2300
Piter;5000;
Maikal;2000;
Maikal2;;2400
Tom;1000;1200 ?

Comment: Thank you. Who tried to run, does not work. IDE editor now no that would see where the error is. Tomorrow all will check and answer.

Comment: no =) and it was my fault. Thank you, everything seems to work.)