# Combine 2 CSV files into one using PHP

Tags: php

I have two CSV files. They have same number of columns but can have different rows. I just need to combine all 10 csv files into one master csv file such that the total number of rows add up.

File 1:

```
John Andy 10 20
Adam Sam 15 25
```

File 2:

```
Sam Eric 34 40
Ryan Rob 15 22
```

Final csv file:

```
John Andy 10 20
Adam Sam 15 25
Sam Eric 34 40
Ryan Rob 15 22
```

Comment: Why can't you read them all separately into a map or object then write them all to one?

Comment: Here is an answer for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417734/combining-2-csv-files

Comment: `$csv_final = file_get_contents('file1.csv') . "\n" . file_get_contents('file2.csv');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `str_getcsv()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

`$file1 = str_getcsv('my_file1.csv');`
`$file2 = str_getcsv('my_file2.csv');`

Then combine the arrays:

`$allfiles = $file1 + $file2 + $file3 [...]`
`$allfiles = array_merge($file1, $file2 [...])`

`array_merge()` will actually re-index them, just combining them (`$file1 + $file2`) will simply append them.

Here's the documentation on `array_merge()`:

http://php.net/array_merge

Finally, once you have your `$allfiles` variable, you can output it via `fputcsv()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

If your files are massive, you'll likely want a different solution. This will (unnecessarily) take up a large amount of memory by placing each file into a variable (then placing them all into one). The solution to that would be to use a pointer, where you'd never really load more than a line into memory at a time.

However, if your files are small, this may work just fine.