# merge csv files using PHP

Tags: php, csv, merge

I have a .csv file which I can use with Google maps API to successfully create map data.

What I'm looking to do is merge 2 (or more) .csv files and display the TOTAL data on the Google map in the same way. They are all in the same format.

I have the paths to the 2 csv files and if need be, a blank .csv file in the same directory where the files could be merged to...

Unfortuantely, the .csv files all have an initial 'header row' which would be awesome to omit when merging...

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very happy. Thanks

edit: I've tried:

```
$data1 = file_get_contents('google_map_data.csv'); 
$data2 = file_get_contents('google_map_data2.csv'); 
$TOTALdata = "google_map_dataALL.csv";

function joinFiles(array $files, $result)
{
    if(!is_array($files)) {
        throw new Exception('`$files` must be an array');
    }

    $wH = fopen($result, "w+");

    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $fh = fopen($file, "r");

        while(!feof($fh))
        {
            fwrite($wH, fgets($fh));
        }

        fclose($fh);
        unset($fh);

        fwrite($wH, "\n"); //usually last line doesn't have a newline
    }

    fclose($wH);
    unset($wH);

    joinFiles(array($data1, $data2), $TOTALdata);
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: $data1 = file_get_contents('google_map_data.csv');
$data2 = file_get_contents('google_map_data2.csv');
$TOTALdata = "google_map_dataALL.csv";
function joinFiles(array $files, $result) {
    if(!is_array($files)) {
        throw new Exception('`$files` must be an array');
    }

    $wH = fopen($result, "w+");

Comment: foreach($files as $file) {
        $fh = fopen($file, "r");
        while(!feof($fh)) {
            fwrite($wH, fgets($fh));
        }
        fclose($fh);
        unset($fh);
        fwrite($wH, "\n"); //usually last line doesn't have a newline
    }
    fclose($wH);
    unset($wH);
 
joinFiles(array($data1, $data2), $TOTALdata);

Comment: Please share the structure of csv file.

Comment: sorry, those 2 comments above, are all part of the same function... couldn't fit it all in one :(

Comment: You should include your code as a part of the question.

Comment: Title,Content,Lat,Long,ProjectID - column for each

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining 2 CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417734/combining-2-csv-files)

Comment: In your while loop, you read one line from the input file using `fgets($fh)`, and write that line to the output file. Now if you are not interested in the _first_ line from every input file - then you call `fgets($fh)` once _before_ the loop, and simply do nothing with the result. (Although, `fgets` is not really the right function to use here in the first place - if your header column values could contain line breaks, it would read only part of that line. To _properly_ handle CSV data, `fgetcsv`/`fputcsv` should be used.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming both files are small, so loading them all in one go should be OK.

The code loads both files then removes the first line off the second one.  It also removes any end of line from the first file, but adds it's own to ensure it always has a new line...

```
$data1 = file_get_contents('google_map_data.csv'); 
$data2 = file_get_contents('google_map_data2.csv'); 
$TOTALdata = "google_map_dataALL.csv";
$data2 = ltrim(strstr($data2, PHP_EOL));
file_put_contents($TOTALdata, rtrim($data1).PHP_EOL.$data2);
```